# Vuejs reactivity check before vue set?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Hello i have a function that recieves a percentage of download of a file, and i use vue set to add the property to the object cuz it's not reactive yet, now this function gets called every second to update the percentage and i'm wondering if it's ok to always use vue set to both set it and update the value, or after i used vue set check if the property it's there and then update it regularly

So i can always call this like this

```
SettaPerc(fileIndex = -1, profIndex = -1,perc = 0) {
            if (profIndex === -1) {
                this.$set(this.file[fileIndex], "perc", perc);
            } else {
                this.$set(this.file[profIndex].linkondi[fileIndex], "perc", perc);
            }
        },
```

Or it's better to do this

```
        SettaPerc(fileIndex = -1, profIndex = -1, perc = 0) {
        if (profIndex === -1) {
            if (this.file[fileIndex].perc === undefined) {
                this.$set(this.file[fileIndex], "perc", perc);
            } else {
                this.file[fileIndex].perc = perc
            }
        } else {
            if (this.file[profIndex].linkondi[fileIndex] === undefined) {
                this.$set(this.file[profIndex].linkondi[fileIndex], "perc", perc);
            } else {
                this.file[profIndex].linkondi[fileIndex] = perc
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *real downside* to use this.$set, it's completely fine.

My suggestion would be

```
  SettaPerc(fileIndex = -1, profIndex = -1,perc = 0) {
      if (profIndex === -1) 
        return this.$set(this.file[fileIndex], "perc", perc); 

      return this.$set(this.file[profIndex].linkondi[fileIndex], "perc", perc);           
  },
```

So you could get rid of the additional else block